# Dynamo DB and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-dynamodb

How can we connect the dynamodb to the rails application? I understand that for a database like mysql and sqlite we can simply configure the database.yml but I dont have any clue of how to connect to DynamoDB.

Also, How do we create the active record model for the dynamodb?

Comment: You can follow [DynamoDb](https://github.com/Veraticus/Dynamoid) link, It may helps you.

Comment: You might find this tutorial useful [DynamoDB with Rails](https://blog.faodailtechnology.com/step-by-step-guide-to-using-dynamodb-with-rails-application-i-a676cb9ba4df).

Answer (score 1):

For the DynamoDb configuration on a Rails app, you need to install the [aws official gem](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby), then the sdk will look for credentials, you must initialize them on the yml file where you have other environment variables. I found this [aws post](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3D6U6WSFGOK2H/A-New-and-Standardized-Way-to-Manage-Credentials-in-the-AWS-SDKs) very usefull  about credential management. After this all set up you can write objects to amazon DynamoDb the documentation is very clear [aws documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/DynamoDB/Resource.html) about dynamo they have some code samples.